# Converting image grayscale pixel values to alpha values

Tags: python, opencv

Is it possible to convert image grayscale pixel values to alpha values in python using libraries like OpenCV, Pillow and scikit-image?

**This is a test program using OpenCV:**

```
path = "e:/python/sampleImage.tif"
src = cv2.imread(path, -1)
print("shape: ",src.shape)
print("co_pixel value3: ",src[970,1000])
cv2.imshow("Displaying only blue channels",src)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An image with alpha channel is just an image with 4 channels: 3 colors (B, G, R in OpenCV), and the alpha channel. So let's say you have your color image `src`. Then

```
import numpy as np
gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_w_alpha = np.dstack( (src, gray) )
```

`np.dstack` adds the alpha channel as the 4th channel to your color image.

I don't understand though, *why* you'd want to do that, so if that doesn't answer your question, maybe you need to elaborate on it.

EDIT: Following your comments, maybe you're looking for alpha blending?

```
import cv2
# Load the tiff
tif = cv2.imread('tmp/Nixon.tif')
h,w,c = tif.shape
alpha = cv2.cvtColor(tif, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
tif_a = cv2.cvtColor(tif, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
tif_a[:,:,3] = alpha  #  now you have an image whose alpha channel equals the greyscale values, 
#                        but I'm not sure what good that is
# load a background image
img = cv2.imread('tmp/PA110602.JPG')
img = cv2.resize(img, (w,h))  #  for blending, both images need to be of same size
# blend the two images, using the greyscale version of tif as alpha values
blend = cv2.add(
        alpha.reshape((*alpha.shape,1))/255.0*tif.astype(float),
        (1.0-alpha.reshape((*alpha.shape,1))/255.0)*img.astype(float),
        dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
```

[image: Foreground, background, and blended image]

As you can see, where Nixon's image is almost black, e.g. in his jacket and hair, the background image is visible, and where Nixon's image is bright, e.g. his collar and face, the background image is barely visible.

The code for blending looks so awkward, because

- we can not multiply a `h-by-w` image with a `h-by-w-by-c` image, but we CAN multiply a `h-by-w-by-1` image with a `h-by-w-by-c` image, so we have to add the dimension to `alpha` using `reshape`.
- for the blending, we have to convert the image from uint to float, but once we're done, we want to have uint again.

But do some Googling for "alpha blending" if this is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: The image I'm using is a 16bit grayscale tif

Comment: Well explained. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting your gray image to BGRA. Then make a copy of the gray image as alpha. Then put the alpha image into the alpha channel of the 3-channel (BGR) gray image.

```
alpha = src.copy()
src = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)
src[:,:,3] = alpha
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: Unfortunately there was some typing error in my question.  Actually my question is, is it possible to convert the pixel values of a grayscale image into  alpha values. Simply putting, i just want to convert the gray-scale tones to transparency data. I tried your code, it is working. but does the src[:,:,3]'s pixel values really matches the alpha values. I'm quit new to python GUI, so please forgive me if my question sounds silly. Thank you.

Comment: The image I'm using is a 16 bit grayscale tif

Comment: I do not know if you can have 16-bit alpha in Python.  Perhaps some one else may be able to advise you better.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible with 8 bit grayscale image.

Comment: My commands should work fine with 8-bit grayscale images.

Comment: yes, it is working fine with 8 bit grayscale images. Thank you.